# Removing part of the string and adding to another

Tags: python, string, url

i have strings like this

```py
str1 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546"
str2 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546231"
str3 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=22432"
```

how can i add only last numbers "5986546" , "5986546231" , "22432" to other string.

I mean I just need to remove somehow `"https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId="` part from strings. And length on this number can vary of course.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "how can i add only last numbers ..." mean? How do you want to "add" them? What's the expected result? Next you talk about removing the numbers from the URL, which is a different question.

Comment: You may want to *parse* the URL and then change it.

Comment: are you looking for substring `?itemId=your_numbers` then use regex

Comment: @timgeb i need output just numbers that goes after itemId=

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single parameter, you can use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) from the standard library:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

str1 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546"

item1 = urlparse(str1).query.split('=')[-1]  # '5986546'
```

For multiple parameters, you can construct a dictionary via [`urllib.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

str2 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546&somevar=5"

args = parse_qs(urlparse(str2).query)
item2 = args['itemId']  # '5986546'
```

Comment: what if the url string have more parameters than just one `itemId`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the split function on the string.

```
str1.split("https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As your URLs do not include more than one `=`, you can use `str.split`

```
id = str1.split('=')[-1] # or [1] in this case no diff
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I know this, that is why I say "As your URLs do not include more than one `=`, you can use `str.split`" !!! I mean in this case, it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

```
import re 

str1 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546"
str2 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=5986546231"
str3 = "https://web2.some.com/hbh/productImages?itemId=22432"

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+?)$')
l = regex.findall(str1)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['5986546']
```

Moreover, the below code will return all in once:

```
all_strings = ''.join( [str1,str2,str3])

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{2,})')
l = regex.findall(all_strings)
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['5986546', '5986546231', '22432']
```

Comment: Why downvote? The answer I have provided is the valid one.